# How do I set a label to a value from a separate table view controller?

Tags: swift, types, timer

So I'm setting up a timer in swift that takes text entered from another view controller. I'm not sure how to set the timer label as the value "timerTime" which has a member called "time" from another controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerTaskName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerTimeSetting: UILabel!

    var timerTask: TaskData?
    var timerTime: TaskData?
    var seconds = 100
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false
    var resumeTapped = false

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func startButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if isTimerRunning == false {
            runTimer()
            self.startButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isTimerRunning = true
        pauseButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.resumeTapped == false {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.resumeTapped = true
            self.pauseButton.setTitle("Resume",for: .normal)
        } else {
            runTimer()
            self.resumeTapped = false
            self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func resetButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
        seconds = 60
        self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        if self.resumeTapped == true {
            self.resumeTapped = false
            self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
        }
        isTimerRunning = false
        pauseButton.isEnabled = false
        startButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    func updateTimer() {
        if seconds < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            //Send alert to indicate "time's up!"
        } else {
            seconds -= 1
            timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        }
    }

    func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hours = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pauseButton.isEnabled = false

        if let task = timerTask {
            timerTaskName.text = task.task
        }

        if let timerTimeLeft = timerTime {
            timerTimeSetting.text = timerTimeLeft.time
        }

        self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to get timerTimeLeft.time into my seconds variable. I've tried many different things but at I'm just stuck.

Comment: What happens? Do you get a crash?

Comment: Well I was just able to set timer Label, but now my timer doesn't run when I press startButtonTapped

Comment: Did you add the timer to the main run loop? `RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)`

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement that, I posted another question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245307/why-wont-this-timer-run)

Comment: i added your piece of code to my runTimer method, I must be making some mistake because my timer still doesn't fire

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the timer to the runloop. This:

```
func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    isTimerRunning = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Should be

```
func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode) // <-- Notice this
    isTimerRunning = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: I added this but my timer still displays but does not fire

Comment: If you put a print statement or breakpoint in `updateTimer` is it getting called?

Comment: I solved the problem by putting timerTimeSetting.text into another variable, but thanks for introducing me to RunLoop in case I need it later